# Is my Hiragana and Katakana handwriting correct?

Tags: katakana, hiragana, handwriting

I don't have a teacher and I'm not going to any Japanese classes. I learn Japanese by myself and on the internet. but Content on the Internet is contradictory. I freaking out that I learned all this wrong. Please tell me my mistakes. TNX

[image: My handwriting]

Comment: [On-/Off-topicness of legibility questions is debatable](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1575/78).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sania san, your handwriting is very good for a beginner. As you continue to practice, you will discover nuances to improve in both your hiragana and katakana (we all do!); but you are doing well. If I were to choose one kana to focus on first in comparing your writing to charts, it would be タ in the katakana syllabary. Kudos to you for taking on Japanese language study all by yourself!